# Get user redirect from referrer url link to product detail page

Tags: laravel, redirect, referrer

I am working on referring system, but I am stuck how to do this. When generate a referrer link for the product I want to redirect the user to that product when any one click on that link example: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/affiliate/referrer_id/product_id** this is the example referrer link.

I generated this link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/affiliate/1/9
```

As we see at the end of the url the product id is present. The product detail page of this id link is this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/9
```

My question is when some one click on the referrer link how to redirect user to this product detail link?

I try this but i am not sure about this is it right or not.
At the **web.php** I declare a route like this

```
 // Affiliate
Route::get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/affiliate/{referrer_id}/{product_id}', 'UsersController@referrerRedirect');
```

At the **UsersController** **referrerRedirect** function

```
public function referrerRedirect($product_id, $referrer_id)
{
    return view();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a product route and controller: There are many ways to setup the route (eg resource controllers and such) this just an example

```
Route::get('products/{product_id}', 'ProductController@get')->name('product');

public function get($product_id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($product_id);
    return view('your_product_view', ['product' => $product]);
}
```

The idea is that you return a redirect to the product route ->name() and pass the param.

```
public function referrerRedirect($product_id, $referrer_id)
{
//do referrel things with the $referrer_id
   return redirect()->route('product', [$product_id]);

//or it may be
return redirect()->route('product', ['product' => $product_id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**web.php**

```
// Affiliate
Route::get('affiliate/{product_id}/{referrer_id}', 'UsersController@referrerRedirect');
```

**UsersController** referrerRedirect function

```
    public function referrerRedirect($product_id, $referrer_id)
{
    // right a query to fetch data from database product table match with $product_id 
    
    $product = Product::where('id', $product_id)->get();

    return view('products.details')->with(compact('product'));
}
```